# UIButton Unwanted Vertical Padding With Autolayout

Tags: ios, uibutton, autolayout

For some reason, my buttons have this strange small vertical padding that I can't get rid of. I'm using autolayout so sizeToFit doesn't do anything.

> [image]

Is there any way to get rid of this padding? I've tried increasing the content hugging priority to required, but it hasn't done anything.

Comment: There is no image at this link http://imgur.com/13zgfyR

Comment: Just fixed it, sorry.

Comment: Running into the same problem